# iOS elements are visible = false, but displayed in UI - Appium xcuitest

Tags: flutter, mobile, appium, appium-ios, xcuitest

I have a problem with some elements from an iOS application. They are displayed in the UI, but in Appium Inspector are visible = false. I have read a lot about this problem, but I was unable to find a solution. The application is developed with Flutter and the developers also tried a lot of solutions using semantics, but non of them worked.

I tried to change the iOS version/simulator but it didn't change the situation
Current iOS/simulator -> iPhone 14 iOS 16.4

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue on multiple occasions, and failed to resolve them too.
I would suggest asking your developer to assign accessibity properties for the element you are tring to access. This way they can mark the Element to be visible = true.
Worked for me in few instances but not for all. Its worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the capability XCUITestOptions.SIMPLE_IS_VISIBLE_CHECK_OPTION to true and check .
https://github.com/appium/WebDriverAgent/commit/fa1a7c5e575c54319593d0b5e033e59ccf34dfbc